# How to compose functions in Yesod in Either like style?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a wrapper over `Either`

```
newtype Answer a = Answer (Either Text a)
```

which can be converted to JSON:

```
instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (Answer a) where
toJSON (Answer (Left msg)) = object
  [ "error"   .= True
  , "message" .= msg
  , "data"    .= Null
  ]
toJSON (Answer (Right val)) = object
  [ "error"   .= False
  , "message" .= pack "OK"
  , "data"    .= val
  ]
```

There are two kinds of answers:

```
errorAnswer :: Text -> Answer a
errorAnswer = Answer . Left

valueAnswer :: a -> Answer a
valueAnswer = Answer . Right
```

I have a set of functions running in `Handler` monad and returning `Answer`.

Some functions test something:

```
checkSomething :: Handler (Answer a) -> Handler (Answer a)
checkSomething action = do
  if sometingIsWrong
    then pure (errorAnswer "Something was wrong")
    else action
```

Other functions manipulate `TVar` variables in `App`:

```
readSomething
  :: (App -> TVar a) -> (a -> Either Text b) -> Handler (Answer a)
readSomething var f =
  readVar var >>= pure . Answer . f
  where
    readVar var = getYesod >>= liftIO . readTVarIO . var
```

It is quite easy to compose these two functions above:

```
handleRequest :: ToJSON a => Handler (Answer a)
handleRequest =
  checkSomething $ readSomething someVar someProjection
```

But it gets hard when I have more checks like `checkSomething`. Plus, I want to put `returnJson` somewhere to return `Value` at the end.

Is there a way to write a handler in `Either` like style (also, `Maybe` like)? For example:

```
handleRequest :: Handler (Answer Int)
handleRequest = do
  checkSomething0 -- Do not continue if (Answer (Left _))
  checkSomething1 -- Do not continue if (Answer (Left _))
  doSomething     -- Everything above was fine
```

One idea would be to add `Alternative` instance to `Handler (Answer a)`, but here is a problem:

```
empty = Answer (Left ???)
```

I'm losing a message here which server supposed to return in case of error.

Comment: You probably want to replace `Handler (Answer a)` with [`ExceptT Text Handler a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT).

Comment: @leftaroundabout and then unwrap `ExceptT` in handlers like `getPageR = runExceptT ...` ?